# How to reduce the code at fluent API in OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have few columns that are not supposed to change by any future update in the table so I have made my fluent API in `OnModelCreating` as follows.

```
base.OnModelCreating(builder);

builder.Entity<UserSetting>()
              .Property(p => p.ID)
                .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
builder.Entity<UserSetting>()
              .Property(p => p.CreatedOn)
                .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
builder.Entity<UserSetting>()
              .Property(p => p.CreatedBy)
                .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
```

I have 40 tables in my project so I have written 120 lines in this method.

Instead of writing 120 lines, Is there any easier way to achieve this.?

**Update:** Here is my base class that inherited by all other classes.

```
public class Common
{        
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Now;
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }       
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }  = System.DateTime.Now;        
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}

public class table1 : Common
{
    //Other Properties...
}
```

Comment: Are all these tables share base class or interface?

Comment: Yes, all model classes from one base class.

Comment: Can you please include that class in the question? And I guess you want apply the above configuration to all classes which inherit that base class, correct?

Comment: use a generic method to convert this cumbersome code into a simple method call

Comment: My Qestion is updated with base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having DRY in mind, I would suggestion you to create your own extension method, like so:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static void InmutableCollumn<TEntity, TProperty>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression) where TEntity : class
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>()
          .Property(propertyExpression)
            .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
    }
}
```

Then you would call it:

```
modelBuilder.InmutableCollumn<UserSetting, Guid>(p => p.Id);
```

That would make your code easier to maintain and a bit less repetitive.

You could even make the method receive a list of expressions, just need to find a way to deal with the property type. Look at this draft:

```
    public static void InmutableCollumn<TEntity>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] propertiesExpression) where TEntity : class
    {
        foreach(var propertyExpression in propertiesExpression)
            modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>()
                .Property(propertyExpression)
                .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
    }
```

So it would be call like this:

```
modelBuilder.InmutableCollumn<UserSetting>(p => p.ID, p => p.CreatedOn);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could do that, the most natural being to move the common code in a *constrained generic* class implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`. Then iterate the model entity types, instantiate the configuration class via reflection and call `ApplyConfiguration` method of the `ModelBuilder` dynamically (or using reflection).

For instance, the configuration class:

```
public class CommonEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : Common
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.ID)
            .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
        builder.Property(p => p.CreatedOn)
            .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
        builder.Property(p => p.CreatedBy)
            .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
    }
}
```

and calling it from inside `OnModelCreating`:

```
var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(Common).IsAssignableFrom(t.ClrType));
foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
{
    var configurationType = typeof(CommonEntityTypeConfiguration<>)
        .MakeGenericType(entityType.ClrType);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(
        (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(configurationType));
}
```

This allows you to generically configure fluently all the aspects of the base class, not only the `AfterSaveBehavior` of some properties.

Comment: An Un-Handlec exception raised "Configure<TEntity>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @Ramesh Sorry, forgot that non generic `Entity` method is not returning generic `EntityTypeBuilder`. Now is working (tested :)